# UITableView background with alpha color causing problem with UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background, alpha

I'm trying to get a semi-transparent uitableview, with this color

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(247.0/255.) green:(151.0/255.0) blue:(121.0/255.0) alpha:0.38];
```

It's ok if there are only empty cells, but when a cell has content inside, the background turns more solid.
It's as if the cell itself had the same table background, so that transparency is multiplied.

The cells with content inside are semi-transparent, but with a wrong alpha.

The table background is set correctly

```
self.myTable.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
```

The background of the cell is set to clear and not opaque

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.opaque = NO;
```

So, why does it has this behavior?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using a transparent UITableView and putting a semi-transparent UIView behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by the caching of the cell. Have you tried disabling the cache? It's very inefficient ofcourse, but it might help you find a solution for this issue, if it's indeed the UITableViewCell cache is the problem.

You can disable it by not using the "dequeueReusableCell" function in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even disabling cache didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the exact same problem.

After breaking on the -(void)setBackgroundColor on the UITableViewCell class, it seems that it is being called by UITableView internal methods just after the

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

method of your delegate.
Another workaround is to overload the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method in your delegate and set the background color of your cells here.