# Static UITableViewCell changes during viewWillAppear not reflected in display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using some static `UITableViewCell`'s configured in the Storyboard to display some setting information.

Some of the other cells should be disabled if one of the other settings is toggled off.

In order to put the cells into the proper state, during `viewWillAppear` I read the settings from NSUserDefaults and then change the cells accordingly.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"OtherCellEnabled"]) {
            [self otherCell].alpha = 1.0;
            [self otherCell].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Changing alpha to 0.3");
            [self otherCell].alpha = 0.3;
            [self otherCell].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
```

The problem is that when I actually run the program, even though it says in the log that the alpha is changed, the alpha doesn't actually change. The `userInteractionEnabled` does seem to stick, but the alpha is left at 1.0.

It's not a problem of cell reuse, or cell's not being instantiated in time, because the other settings can be changed just fine.

Changing it from cell.alpha to cell.contentView.alpha works, but that is a different setting.

It seems like all of the settings "stick" except for the `alpha` setting, which somehow is getting overwritten.

Comment: Have you tried [cell setNeedsDisplay]; ?

Comment: As I said, if I actually print the `cell.alpha` once the table is all done loading, it is set to the incorrect value of 1.0. So the value isn't even being saved. If I do things like change the color, they do get saved, so I don't think it's a drawing problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering my own question because I was able to solve it.

First, I tried putting the alpha change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but that didn't work either. After a lot of tinkering, I've come to the conclusion that `UITableViewCell`'s alpha setting is somehow special in that it keeps getting overwritten or set to 1.0.

I found two fixes:

**First**, instead of doing the change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, do it in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `willDisplayCell`. For whatever reason, changing the cell's alpha in this method will actually stick. Of course, if you do it this way you have to re-arrange your logic so that the changes are done on a cell-by-cell basis, i.e.:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell  
                                         forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (cell == [self otherCell]) {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"OtherCellEnabled"]) {
        cell.alpha = 1.0;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Changing alpha to 0.3");
        cell.alpha = 0.3;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
}
```

As I said, I'm not sure exactly why this works in `willDisplayCell` but not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Others seem uncertain also:

[What is -[UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for)

[UITableView background with alpha color causing problem with UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916348/uitableview-background-with-alpha-color-causing-problem-with-uitableviewcell)

**The other solution** is to, instead of using the problematic alpha, use another setting which will achieve the same effect. In my case, that was the `contentView.alpha` and the `backgroundColor`. For whatever reason, these settings will stick, and you can even set them in `viewWillAppear` and it will work as expected:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"OtherCellEnabled"]) {
            [self otherCell].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
            [self otherCell].contentView.alpha = 1.0;
            [self otherCell].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Changing alpha to 0.3");
            [self otherCell].backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.3];
            [self otherCell].contentView.alpha = 0.3;
            [self otherCell].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
}
```

The disadvantage to the second approach is that now you are overwriting the Storyboard's cell color settings, but you could work around that by asking the storyboard for the color if you care about that.

I'm not sure why `cell.alpha` is treated differently. Maybe something about the way static cells are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hint the cell should be redrawn after your `if { .. } else { .. }`, by using `setNeedsDisplay`:

```
[self otherCell setNeedsDisplay]
```

Based on your comment, how do you get to `otherCell`?
[Is this a post that might help](http://mark.themoseleys.com/2010/07/uitableviewcell-wont-update-arghhhh/)?

Comment: It's not a question of the cell drawing or not. If I actually print the alpha value when it is done drawing the alpha value is left at 1.0.

Comment: These were static cells, so otherCell is just an IBOutlet I hooked up in the Storyboard. That post wasn't the problem, either, because all the other things about the cell change (like `userInteractionEnabled`). The cell I'm getting from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the correct cell, just the alpha gets reset somewhere between getting dequeued and being displayed.